# Sum of subspaces is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I've found today a task:

Let $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $V$. Prove, that $A\cup B$ is a subspace only, if $A\subset B$ or $B \subset A$.

Please explain, why my counterexample isn't correct.

Suppose, that $A$ is a first coordinate and $B$ is a second coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $A \nsubseteq B$ and $B \nsubseteq A$, but $A\cup B$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: In your example, $A$ and $B$ are lines, their union is a cross, not the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The same applies if subspace is replaced by subgroup and vector space is replaced by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{(x,0,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $B=\{(0,x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, then
$$
A\cup B=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid z=(x,0,0)\;\text{ or }\;z=(0,x,0)\;\text{ for some }\;x\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$
Is it clear now? Which of the properties of being a linear subspace does it violate?

Comment: Yes now it's clear, and I know how to think about it. Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Of course, if violate, that not every sum of elements will be in this set. Eg. (5,0,0) + (0,6,0)=(5,6,0) which isn't in it

Comment: @Steve: Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, if possible, $\exists\alpha$ and $\beta\in V$ such that $\alpha\in A$ and $\beta\in B$ and $\alpha,\beta\notin A\cap B$. But as $A\cup B$ is a subspace, $\implies a\alpha+b\beta\in A\cup B$. Now, If $a\alpha+b\beta\in A\implies a\alpha+b\beta=\gamma\in A\implies \beta=(\gamma-a\alpha)b^{-1}\in A$, which is a contradiction. Thus, one of them has to be contained in the other.

Answer (score 1):

consider two subspaces $S$ and $T$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $S=\{(x,y,z):y=0,z=0\}$, $T=\{(x,y,z):x=0,z=0\}$, let $\alpha=(1,0,0)\in S$, $\beta=(0,1,0)\in T$, Then $\alpha+\beta=(1,1,0)\notin T$ and also $\alpha+\beta=(1,1,0)\notin S$  also $\alpha+\beta=(1,1,0)\notin S\cup T$